# syslog to log a c string containt http request data

Tags: c, printf, newline, syslog

I wrote a program that will read some data (HTTP Request) from a server and transfer it to another server. My program is running as a service in an Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

When the program reads data in HTTP request form, I can use printf to printout the data as below image.

[image]

When I uses syslog to log the data and views it using journalctl, the log only shows "xxB blob data".

[image]

Because my data has some newline characters, the syslog will not display it.

Note: my data is declare as:

```
char buf[8192];
```

Please help me to display my data in syslog.

Answer (score 0):

[Syslog](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424) doesn't handle multiline messages. Some syslog agents ([like rsyslog eg.](https://rainer.gerhards.net/2013/09/imfile-multi-line-messages.html)) have support for them in some way, so that could be an option. But you're probably better off rolling your own (eg. by escaping the newlines).